# On Windows, file starting with / is not considered absolute

Tags: java, windows, path, filepath

This surprised me, but apparently, a path on Windows that starts with a slash is not considered absolute.  You need to specify c:.  But surely, there is a difference between `/foo` and `foo`

```
System.out.println(new File(new File("/folder"), "abc"));
System.out.println(new File(new File("/folder"), "abc").isAbsolute());

\folder\abc
false
```

Is this correct behavior?

I want to be able to identify a relative path, such as `foo`, so I can prepend a default directory.  But I would consider `/foo` to be an absolute path and would not prepend the default

Comment: Why would `/foo` be absolute on windows? In windows, no full path starts with a `/`

Comment: /foo is relative to the current selected drive, so it's not absolute.

Comment: Well, it's absolute on the current drive, but I know what you mean

Comment: "absolute on the current drive" is just another way of saying "relative to the current drive". If "absolute" is to have any meaning, it must be that "no matter the context, this always uniquely identifies one path within a system" and that's simply not true if you don't include a drive letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check for "isAbsolute" by string comparisons, just use `Path` and resolve using `defaultDir.resolve(path)`

Consider:

```
var rel = Path.of("relative");
var abs = Path.of("/absolute");

for (Path dir : List.of(Path.of("."), Path.of("abc"),Path.of("/abc"))) {
    System.out.println("dir="+dir);
    System.out.println("dir.resolve("+abs+")="+dir.resolve(abs));
    System.out.println("dir.resolve("+rel+")="+dir.resolve(rel));
}
```

This handles resolving from the default directory path using another path which may be relative or absolute (in sense that it starts with path separator) on Windows or Linux.

Example run from Linux (Windows is same answer but with Windows path separator character).

```
dir=.
dir.resolve(/absolute)=/absolute
dir.resolve(relative)=./relative
dir=abc
dir.resolve(/absolute)=/absolute
dir.resolve(relative)=abc/relative
dir=/abc
dir.resolve(/absolute)=/absolute
dir.resolve(relative)=/abc/relative
```

Comment: Best answer! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the start of your file path begins with a "/" using `Boolean isPathAbsolute = "/foo".startsWith("/")` and use this variable to decide if you prepend the default or not!

Comment: Problem is my code runs in both Windows and Linux, so I need to check for either '/' or '\'

Comment: "/foo".startsWith("/") || "/foo".startsWith("\") 
Will do the job

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I guess I was hoping for something a bit more built-in to figure out if I need to prepend a default directory